How to SpanQuery the evaluations in arize phoenix
I'm making a RAG application and I use arize phoenix for my logs.
I can make evaluations but it seems like I can't make a query that gets the evaluations result in a dataframe.
Does anyone have a SpanQuery that can get the evaluations result?
I tried the
px.Client().get_spans_dataframe()

method that is supposed to get every attributes but it doesn't work with evaluations result.
